# VBA Function Module Not Calculating All Output Values

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have mainly 2 modules.
The main module "TestMain" has a function that writes the code of the second module "MyNewTest" which should perform some calculations.

(The reason for that is that the code is dependent on the input, so for each input the code will be different).

For simplicity I wrote a very simple code to highlight my problem.

The problem is that the function is only calculating the first value of the input array and putting its result in all the remaining rows.

Although the second module code is being updated when I run the main sub. But the results are only according to the first "second module" (which is corresponding to the first row).
(For Example in sheet 4 all the second column values are 23 (corresponding to the first row input).

Any idea about how I can solve the problem ?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddNewWorkBookTEST()

Dim nextline As Long, LastUsedRowList As Long
Dim CodeString As String

Dim x As Long
Dim KWATT As Double


Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

LastUsedRowList = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To LastUsedRowList
    KWATT = Sheet4.Cells(x, 1)
    CodeString = CodeStringGenerator(KWATT)

    ''Update the module code
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("MyNewTest").CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("MyNewTest").CodeModule
        nextline = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines nextline, CodeString
    End With

CallOtherModule x
''Calling the function in the second module (where the code was copied).
'''Cannot call the function directly from this sub, since excel will crash:Call MyNewTest.SortedArray(x)

Next x


End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub CallOtherModule(ItemsCounter As Long)
    Call MyNewTest.SortedArray(ItemsCounter)
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''The function that writes the code of the second module as String
Function CodeStringGenerator(KWATT As Double) As String

CodeStringGenerator = "'Option Explicit" & vbCrLf & "Public Function 
SortedArray(ItemsCounter As Long) As Variant()" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "Dim TempSortedArray() As Variant" & vbCrLf _
& "Sheet4.Cells(ItemsCounter, 2) = " & KWATT + 5 & vbCrLf _
& "End Function" & vbCrLf

End Function
```

Comment: Forgot to include an example of input/output.

18, 23;

20, 23;

10, 23;

9, 23;

9, 23;

10, 23;

The first column in sheet 4 is the input, the second column is the output of the function (in this case input +5).

Comment: What is the overall problem you're trying to solve? I strongly suspect that you can solve it without "generating" code. Designing and implementing a set of functions in a code module and/or a set of classes would be a far more robust solution for you in the long run.

Comment: The basic problem is the following:
- Mainly 2 inputs: 1) Total Load, and 2) Number of Sets
- Depending on the number of sets, the code will be different (each set has a for loop (inside of the other for loops). Therefore if I have 2 sets, the code will be different than that in 5 sets case (since I will have here 5 for loops inside each others instead of 2, and also more variables).
Therefore I cannot restrict it in one code.
The code works well if I have one set of input, but in the above case I am trying to take many sets of inputs instead of entering them manually each time. @PeterT

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to sort a multi-dimensional array with varying depths (not known until runtime). Take a look at [this code by Craig Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx) for his `QSortInPlace` function that might help you.

Comment: Actually I do not have any problem with sorting. Sorting is working well. My only problem is that when I give it an array of inputs, it only gives the result of the first input in all the remaining inputs. Although the second code (generated) is being updated while running. But it is not taking its result every time it updates. Only the result of the first generated code is the output for all the inputs.

Comment: Saw this question which is somehow related to my problem. But the solution did not work in my case.         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530915/excel-vba-code-module-not-updated-during-run/56434519?noredirect=1#comment99463915_56434519